# SpecialCells method of Excel Range strange behaviour

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to find blank cells from a certain range using SpecialCells method of excel range object.
When i am trying to execute following code i get a exception as "No cells found".

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
End Sub
```

Steps:-

1. Open a new Excel instance.
2. Press ALT + F11/ Open VBE
3. Insert a new Module
4. Paste the above code and run test macro as specified above.

**Output Received:**

Runtime Error '1004'. No Cells Found.

**Output Expected:**

$A$1:$D$4

**Case 1:**

Now if i do any operation of cell A1. Operation such as giving fill color, etc. Call the test() macro then it does not throw exception.

**Output Received:**

$A$1

**Output Expected:**

$A$1:$D$4

**Case 2:**

Suppose if i give any value in cell B3. Call the test() macro, exception is not thrown.

**Output Received:**

$B$1:$B$2,$A$1:$A$3

**Output Expected:**

$A$1:$D$4

**Case 3:**

If i try to edit value or fill the cell outside the range "A1:D4" for example E10 and execute test() method then it gives me the proper output.

**Output Received:**

$A$1:$D$4

Note: Execute each Case with a new excel instance.

Comment: + 1 For a nicely described question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is `SpecialCells` "looks" at the `UsedRange` when returning a range.

So using `SpecialCells` on an unused sheet will return `Runtime Error '1004'. No Cells Found.` *(As an aside always use error handling with SpecialCells)*

When you change cell A1, that becomes the sheets `UsedRange`, hence your Case 1 return of "A1"

The code below looks to return Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) for

1. A blank sheet - fails
2. The sheet with A10 filled in - `A1:A4`
3. The sheet with A10 cleared - `A1:A4`
4. The sheet with the usedrange reset (which is effectively 1) - fails

   ```
   Sub Test()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Sheets.Add
   On Error Resume Next
   'blank sheet
   Debug.Print "Blank sheet " & ws.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
   'enter in A10
   ws.[a10] = "test"
   Debug.Print "With A10 " & ws.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
   'clear a10
   ws.[a10].ClearContents
   Debug.Print "With A10 cleared " & ws.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
   'reset range
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   Debug.Print "With A10 cleared and range reset" & ws.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
   On Error GoTo 0
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`.SpecialCells` work with the used range of a worksheet and not specific cells unless the specific cells fall within the used range.

To test `Specialcells` on an entirely new sheet will give you the error because the usedrange is just $A$1. If $A$1 is colored then you will not get an error as expected in CASE 2 above.

You have to use `Specialcells` with utmost care. Here is an example which will not give you an error on a new sheet.

```
Sub Sample()
    If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column > 1 Or ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row > 1 Then
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
    End If
End Sub
```

Now type something in Cell D5. Say "Blah Blah"

Now run this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A1:D4").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
End Sub
```

You will notice that this will work because the range is within the UsedRange Address.