# Check If Any Cell In A Range Has A Value

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm having trouble with confirming if any cell in a specified range contains any value. Hoping someone can help me out with the syntax.

Thanks in advance

```
        For i = 1 To DataRange.Rows.Count
            CheckCells = If(Qty > 0 And WS1.Range("Sheet1!A" & i & ":Sheet1!Z" & i).Value <> "", "HasValue", "NoValue")
        Next i
```

Comment: shouldn't you replace that `If(...` with `iif(...` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SpencerBarnes but this doesn’t seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: 1) Does it give an error message? 2) You should use `AndAlso` instead of `And`: [What is the difference between And and AndAlso in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/302047/1115360) 3) You might need `DirectCast(WS1.Range("Sheet1!A" & i & ":Sheet1!Z" & i), Excel.Range).Value`.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes That should be done if and only if the code is VBA.  If it's VB.NET, then `If(...` is by far the preferred approach as it's a built-in operator with type safety and short-circuiting vs. a library function with `Object` parameters and full evaluation of its arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by using the following code.

```
                For i = 1 To DataRange.Rows.Count
                    If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Range("Parts!Z" & R & ":Parts!AI" & R)) > 0 Then
                        CheckCells = "HasValue"
                    Else
                        CheckCells = "NoValue"
                    End If
                Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the cells to examine each one:

```
Dim r = xl.Range("A1", "D4")
Dim nCells = r.Cells.Count
Dim isAllBlank = True

For i = 1 To nCells
    If DirectCast(r.Cells(i), Excel.Range).Value IsNot Nothing Then
        isAllBlank = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next

checkCells = If(isAllBlank, "NoValue", "HasValue")
```

Where `xl.Range` is the range you need to check.

I tried to use `range.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)`, but it was a [bit moody about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753405/specialcells-method-of-excel-range-strange-behaviour).